# YAML anchor as a placeholders in URL string

Tags: yaml, snakeyaml, property-placeholder

Trying to use anchors in an additive way,
Following YAML code will not work but can explain what I want it to do

```
  endpoint:
    data.updates.index.name: &UPDATES-INDEX-NAME "data-updates"
    meta.data.type.name: &DATA-TYPE-NAME "meta-data"
    last.run.type.name: &RUN-TYPE-NAME "lastrun"
    search.ctx: *UPDATES-INDEX-NAME "/" *DATA-TYPE-NAME "/_search"
    search.lastrun: *UPDATES-INDEX-NAME "/" *RUN-TYPE-NAME "/_search"
    update.lastrun: *UPDATES-INDEX-NAME "/" *RUN-TYPE-NAME "/"
```

a1: &anchor1 "hello"
a2: &anchor2 "moon"
property: *anchor1 "-" *anchor2

property should yield "hello-moon"
is it possible at all? tried also using ${} instead of anchors

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with YAML. The anchor/alias feature was designed for serializing cyclic data structures, not for re-using values inside expressions. In YAML, there are no expressions (well, except for the `!!merge` tag for YAML 1.1 which is outdated and does not help you here). You need to do all operations you want to do on your data while or after loading.

A possible way to do it:

```
endpoint:
  data.updates.index.name: "data-updates"
  meta.data.type.name: "meta-data"
  last.run.type.name: "lastrun"
  search.ctx: "{{data.updates.index.name}}/{{meta.data.type.name}}/_search"
  search.lastrun: "{{data.updates.index.name}}/{{last.run.type.name}}/_search"
  update.lastrun: "{{data.updates.index.name}}/{{last.run.type.name}}/"
```

As you see, I used non-YAML markup (in this case, mustache-like) as placeholder. You would need to postprocess the data after loading in order to replace the placeholders with proper content.